# Unable to access R from QGIS 2.18.9 on Macbook

Tags: r, macos-sierra, qgis

I have been unable to run R from within QGIS on my Macbook. I have R version 3.4.0 installed and QGIS 2.18.9 on macOSX Sierra.

"The error message I receive is

Missing dependency.This algorithm cannot be run :-( 
This algorithm requires R to be run.Unfortunately, it seems that R is not installed
in your system, or it is not correctly configured to be used from QGIS 
Click here to know more about how to install and configure R to be used with QGIS"

[Error Image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSKdX.png)

Comment: Did you [try this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200793/integrating-r-in-qgis-with-mac-os-el-captain-missing-dependencies)?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same thing on my MAC.  Researching discovered that the MacOS X from El Capitan and later (Sierra is later) implemented some stringent sandboxing security that doesn't allow R to be seen from the QGIS location.  Hence the error.  So far I have not discovered a workable solution. The solutions suggested for El Capitan do not work for Sierra.